# Validate GraphQL Schema against a sample JSON object

Tags: json, graphql

I want to validate Graphql Schema against a Sample JSON document whether the sample JSON document has all the required fields or not.

As you can see from the below Graphql schema `id`, `name` are required fields and sample JSON object also has those properties. Desirable `validateMySampleJSON(schema, sampleJSON)` should return true in this case.

```
import {
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLString,
} from 'graphql';

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Book',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    name: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    genre: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery,
});

const sampleJSON = {
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'Awesome Book',
};

const isValid = validateMySampleJSON(schema, sampleJSON);

console.log(isValid);  // true


const anotherSampleJSON = {
  'id': '1',
  'genre': 'mystery'
};

const isValid = validateMySampleJSON(schema, anotherSampleJSON);

console.log(isValid);  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution using GraphQL tools, then the answer is no as of today. I don't see any validate function out of the box. However you can achieve this using a combination of other tools.

1. You can cover the GraphQL schema to JSON Schema using `graphql-2-json-schema` package.
2. Once you have the JSON Schema, you can use `jsonschema` package to load the schema and validate the data against it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried this approach and the problem with `graphql-2-json-schema` is, it does not consider `GraphQLNonNull ` as a required field after creating JSON schema and another issue using this npm is, this generates JSON schema `draft-6` but I want to have generated JSON schema for draft-7 specs.